# Transform transition on hover exit

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using 'translate3d' with 'transition' on hover to move a div into view.

This is working correctly upon hover, but on exit, I would like it to transition back to out of view. Currently, it just disappears.

Everything I have tried isn't working, so I was hoping someone may be able to point out the glaring mistake I am making?

See my pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeMxoB

And here is the CSS:

```
  a.box-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a.box-item img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;  
}

a.box-item .text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;        
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

a.box-item .text h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

a.box-item:hover {
    background: #000;
}

a.box-item:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

a.box-item:hover .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

a.box-item:hover .text h2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: It’s because you are changing the opacity back from 1 to 0 at the same time - but your transition is specifically set up to cover changes of the `transform` property only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `"transition: all 0.35s;"` instead of `"transition: transform 0.35s;"` on

```
a.box-item .text {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;        
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.35s;
        transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    }
```

this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `transition: transform 2s, opacity 1s 1s;` on .text element

```
transition: transform 2s, opacity 1s 1s;


a.box-item .text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;        
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 2s, opacity 1s 1s;
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to trigger all efects with same time, just use this style transition: all 0.35s;

Answer (score 0):

Use **"transition: all 0.35s;" instead of "transition: transform 0.35s;"**. it will work.

```
a.box-item .text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;        
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
```